# Laravel mock external service

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I have some class that creates user "integration" and check API credentials using external API:

```
class IntegrationService
{
    public function create(array $params)
    {
        $api = new IntegrationApi();

        if (!$api->checkCredentials($params['api_key'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid credentials');
        }

        // storing to DB
        
        return 'ok'; // just for example
    }
}
```

IntegrationApi class:

```
class IntegrationApi
{
    public function checkCredentials(string $apiKey): bool
    {
        // some external api calls

        return false; // just for example
    }
}
```

I need to create unit tests for IntegrationService class. I'm trying to mock IntegrationApi class in my test before creating test integration, but my test fails with that exception...

```
class TestIntegrationService extends TestCase
{
    public function test_create()
    {
        $service = new IntegrationService();

        $this->mock(IntegrationApi::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('checkCredentials')->withArgs(['apiKey'])->once()->andReturnTrue();
        });

        $res = $service->create(['api_key' => '123']);

        $this->assertEquals('ok', $res);
    }
}
```

It seems that the IntegrationApi object was not mocked as expected, but I haven't any idea why. Have I applied object mocking correctly in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand Dependency Injection and [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) concepts.

For first, never ever use `new` keyword in Laravel projects - use dependency injection through constructor:

```
class IntegrationService
{
    private IntegrationApi $api;
    public function __construct(IntegrationApi $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }
    public function create(array $params)
    {
        if (!$this->api->checkCredentials($params['api_key'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid credentials');
        }

        // storing to DB
        
        return true; // never use magic strings. But in this case - void be preferred - throw exceptions on error and return nothing
    }
}
```

test in this case be like

```
public function setUp()
{
   $this->mockApi = Mockery::mock(IntegrationApi::class);
   $this->service = new IntegrationService($this->mockApi);
}
public function testCreateOk()
{
    $this->mockApi->shouldReceive('checkCredentials')->withArgs(['apiKey'])->once()->andReturnTrue();
    $this->assertTrue($this->service->create(['apiKey']));
}

public function testCreateError()
{
    $this->mockApi->shouldReceive('checkCredentials')->withArgs(['apiKey'])->once()->andReturnFalse();
    $this->expectsException(Exception::class);
    $this->service->create(['apiKey']);
}
```

Comment: hi(привет), can you please advise me ? how to test this code ? Thank you
class Kodik
{
    public function importGenres(): void
    {
        $response = Http::kodik()->get('genres', [
            'token' => config('services.kodik.token'),
            'types' => 'anime,anime-serial',
            'genres_type' => 'shikimori',
        ])->object();

        $genres = $response->results;

        foreach ($genres as $genre) {
            Genre::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => Str::ucfirst(trim($genre->title)),
            ]);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @AlexBlack https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing

Comment: I read. But I don’t understand how I can test that the data is saved correctly. What do I need to test? Can I have an example?

Comment: Umm, u must fake Http, set the fake responce with body, than call your function and assert that faked responce store in DB

Comment: As far as I know, unit tests should not work with a database. And do only imitation

Comment: Yes and no. If you want true unit - add repository layer in your app - and mock them - because you cannot mock ActiveRecord. If you want result - check database.

Answer (score 2):

You can never directly use `new` when you want to add tests, it hardwires to the implementation class so your mock will not be used.

You need to use Dependency injection / the Service Container :

```
class IntegrationService
{
    public function create(array $params)
    {
        $api = app(IntegrationApi::class);
```

This allows the implementation (dynamically returned from the `app` function) to be swapped to the mock object.
Laravel will take care of calling `new` if nothing was bound when this code runs outside of the test context.

---

As Maksim noted in the comments, constructor injection is the other way that avoids using `app()`:

```
class IntegrationService
{
    protected $api;
    public function __construct(IntegrationApi $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }
    public function create(array $params)
    {
        if (!$this->api->checkCredentials ...
```

n.b.: You do not need to manually provide/define these args/their positions to get your Service. If you also request the Service using `app()`/injection in your Controller, Laravel will automatically take care of that (using Reflection).

Comment: Why app()? Constructor injection is clear and pretty way

Comment: Constructor injection would also require them to instantiate `IntegrationService` with those means (which they *should* obv), and also add a constructor to start with. But I agree that it would be even cleaner.